# VS 2013 SDK: How to develop a simple selected-text decoration extension?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

### Scenario

Lets take as an example this random code, it's in **VB.Net**, but just to demonstrate the **VB.Net** extension behavior of what I pretend to do:

```
Dim regEx As New Regex("Dog", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim text As String = "One Dog!, Two Dogs!, three Dogs!"

Dim matchesPos As IEnumerable(Of MatchPosition) = GetMatchesPositions(regEx, text, 0)
```

With the **Ctrl + K + C** hotkey in Visual Studio I can comment the entire block of code getting this result:

```
'Dim regEx As New Regex("Dog", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

'Dim text As String = "One Dog!, Two Dogs!, three Dogs!"

'Dim matchesPos As IEnumerable(Of MatchPosition) = GetMatchesPositions(regEx, text, 0)
```

---

### Question

I pretend to develop an extension like that, but the expected result should has this format, all the code enclosed in an `<Example>` tag for XML documentation:

```
''' <example>
''' Dim regEx As New Regex("Dog", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
'''
''' Dim text As String = "One Dog!, Two Dogs!, three Dogs!"
'''
''' Dim matchesPos As IEnumerable(Of MatchPosition) = GetMatchesPositions(regEx, text, 0)
''' </example>
```

At first view it seems easy to do, all the logic is just comment the lines with three quotes `'''` (even the empty lines) and add the `<Example>` tag, but I'm not sure what tool(s), kind of project, guideline, or code sample I need to start developing this.

I need specific information, help, or a code sample. Just... anything.

---

### Research

The **[Visual Studio Extensibility Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458154.aspx)** reference on **MSDN** sends me to the **[MSDN Code Gallery](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/)** site, but here, I only can find a **[VSX Project SubType](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBVSXProjectSubType-e829fe00)** sample (which I'm not sure whether is what I'm looking for), however, when I try to run the solution, which is composed by three projects, the projects can't load because my IDE, **VS 2013**, says:

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.

This makes me think that maybe my IDE is missing a required component?.

I also searched a lot in Google ..without success of course, I downloaded and unpacked the MSI installer of **[Copy As HTML](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf)** extension, which seems to be a simple extension that could help me to understand how to start doing this, when unpacking I expected to encounter a souce code, but instead that I encountered a compiled dll assembly, so, I imagine that all the other extensions on MSDN code library does not has any source code, and that means I don't have any source-code reference to see and understand how can be done this task.

I also analyzed much questions in **StackOverflow** tagges as `visual-studio-extensions`, but I didn't find the solution, just specific question for specific codes or **VSIX** installers.

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to this question [get the selected text of the editor window..visual studio extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868127/get-the-selected-text-of-the-editor-window-visual-studio-extension) I was able to understand the steps to retrieve the text editor instance, and with a little more of research in the object inspector I found the way to replace the text, this is essential code of my VS Package:

```
''' <summary>
''' This function is the callback used to execute a command when the a menu item is clicked.
''' See the Initialize method to see how the menu item is associated to this function using
''' the OleMenuCommandService service and the MenuCommand class.
''' </summary>
Private Sub MenuItemCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Show a Message Box to prove we were here
    Dim uiShell As IVsUIShell = TryCast(GetService(GetType(SVsUIShell)), IVsUIShell)
    Dim clsid As Guid = Guid.Empty
    Dim result As Integer
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(uiShell.ShowMessageBox(0, clsid, "VSPackage2", String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", Me.GetType().Name), String.Empty, 0, OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK, OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST, OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO, 0, result))

    Me.ModifySelectedText()

End Sub

Private Sub ModifySelectedText()

    Dim selectionSpan As VirtualSnapshotSpan = Me.GetSelection(Me.GetCurrentViewHost).StreamSelectionSpan
    Dim selectedText As String = selectionSpan.SnapshotSpan.GetText

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    sb.AppendLine("''' <example>")
    For Each line As String In selectedText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("''' {0}", line))
    Next
    sb.AppendLine("''' </example>")

    selectionSpan.Snapshot.TextBuffer.Replace(selectionSpan.SnapshotSpan, sb.ToString)

End Sub

Private Function GetCurrentViewHost() As IWpfTextViewHost
    ' code to get access to the editor's currently selected text cribbed from
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd884850.aspx
    Dim txtMgr As IVsTextManager = DirectCast(GetService(GetType(SVsTextManager)), IVsTextManager)
    Dim vTextView As IVsTextView = Nothing
    Dim mustHaveFocus As Integer = 1
    txtMgr.GetActiveView(mustHaveFocus, Nothing, vTextView)
    Dim userData As IVsUserData = TryCast(vTextView, IVsUserData)
    If userData Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim viewHost As IWpfTextViewHost
        Dim holder As Object = Nothing
        Dim guidViewHost As Guid = DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost
        userData.GetData(guidViewHost, holder)
        viewHost = DirectCast(holder, IWpfTextViewHost)
        Return viewHost
    End If
End Function

''' Given an IWpfTextViewHost representing the currently selected editor pane,
''' return the ITextDocument for that view. That's useful for learning things 
''' like the filename of the document, its creation date, and so on.
Private Function GetTextDocumentForView(viewHost As IWpfTextViewHost) As ITextDocument
    Dim document As ITextDocument = Nothing
    viewHost.TextView.TextDataModel.DocumentBuffer.Properties.TryGetProperty(GetType(ITextDocument), document)
    Return document
End Function

''' Get the current editor selection
Private Function GetSelection(viewHost As IWpfTextViewHost) As ITextSelection
    Return viewHost.TextView.Selection
End Function
```

Since I didn't received an answer for my question before, I would ask a consequent question which is in essence the same question:

My question is, is that the right way to develop a simple text decoration extension?, The span and virtual spans and stream spans and a lot of members like that really confuses me, it is safe the modification that I'm performing on the selected text?.

Comment: Start **reading** at the [Extending Visual Studio Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx).

Comment: And install the Visual Studio SDK for your version of Visual Studio https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dOWNLOAD+%22vISUAL+sTUDIO+sdk%22

Comment: Thankyou both for comment. I have much to read. I just have a little question to follow the right path, in the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx docs at the top of the page it explains there are various kinds of extensions, If I understood good what I need to develop is a **MEF** component? (that extends the visual studio editor)?. so i should avoid the rest.

Comment: The MSDN docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885492.aspx says `Creating a Text-Relative Adornment Extension: On the File menu, point to New and then click New Project. In the New Project dialog box, expand Visual C# or Visual Basic and then click Extensibility. In the Templates pane, select Editor Text Adornment` however, after installing SDK for my VS 2013, I don't have any additional template than the `Visual Studio Package` template ...why? I can't follow the guide because I don't have what it says I should have. Also,that template doesn't exists in the online templates

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the Visual Studio 2013 SDK Samples from here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VIsual-Studio-2013-SDK-728822a7/view/SamplePack#content but I'm unable to find any example about what I pretend to do (adornate the selected text), and, the visualstudio SDK reference members is too big to find out a reference of this, but I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I figured out how to retrieve and replace the text, however, I have a lot of doubts about what I did, please, see my update. thanks everybody.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Do you still require an answer to this question? By the way, the questions you write are always nicely formatted and clearly written. You deserve an upvote just for that.