# How to get selected text of visual studio 2015 editor windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I want to implement a visual studio 2015 extension to fetch the user selected text in code editor. Than I want to manipulate the selected text.

A have a Button/Command via context menu in the code editor. But I don't know how 
to get the selected text.

I think this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868127/get-the-selected-text-of-the-editor-window-visual-studio-extension) is outdated or I missunderstand the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that your code is already in a class that derives from `Package`.

You can get and modify the selection text like so:

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));

if (dte.ActiveDocument != null)
{
    var selection = (TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;
    string text = selection.Text;

    // Modify the text, for example:
    text = ">>" + text + "<<";

    // Replace the selection with the modified text.
    selection.Text = text;
}
```